# How to convert PascalCase to snake_case?

Tags: php, string, pascalcasing, snakecasing

If I had:

```
$string = "PascalCase";
```

I need

```
"pascal_case"
```

Does PHP offer a function for this purpose?

Comment: Technically, the first example string is PascalCase.

Comment: And the second example string is known as [snake_case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Comment: I know this is 8 yrs late but just wanted to point out that OP clearly typed "pascal_case" instead of "snake_case" since it's about converting the string "PascalCase" to snake case, and not to the string "snake_case".

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
$tests = array(
  'simpleTest' => 'simple_test',
  'easy' => 'easy',
  'HTML' => 'html',
  'simpleXML' => 'simple_xml',
  'PDFLoad' => 'pdf_load',
  'startMIDDLELast' => 'start_middle_last',
  'AString' => 'a_string',
  'Some4Numbers234' => 'some4_numbers234',
  'TEST123String' => 'test123_string',
);

foreach ($tests as $test => $result) {
  $output = from_camel_case($test);
  if ($output === $result) {
    echo "Pass: $test => $result\n";
  } else {
    echo "Fail: $test => $result [$output]\n";
  }
}

function from_camel_case($input) {
  preg_match_all('!([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?=$|[A-Z][a-z0-9])|[A-Za-z][a-z0-9]+)!', $input, $matches);
  $ret = $matches[0];
  foreach ($ret as &$match) {
    $match = $match == strtoupper($match) ? strtolower($match) : lcfirst($match);
  }
  return implode('_', $ret);
}
```

Output:

```
Pass: simpleTest => simple_test
Pass: easy => easy
Pass: HTML => html
Pass: simpleXML => simple_xml
Pass: PDFLoad => pdf_load
Pass: startMIDDLELast => start_middle_last
Pass: AString => a_string
Pass: Some4Numbers234 => some4_numbers234
Pass: TEST123String => test123_string
```

This implements the following rules:

1. A sequence beginning with a lowercase letter must be followed by lowercase letters and digits;
2. A sequence beginning with an uppercase letter can be followed by either:

   - one or more uppercase letters and digits (followed by either the end of the string or an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter or digit ie the start of the next sequence); or
   - one or more lowercase letters or digits.

Comment: It works for CamelCased strings (as openfrog asked), but if you use it with input string for example "r_id" (already "underscored") it trimmes the prefix ("r_"). Good solution, but definitely not universal.

Comment: Curious why you're checking if string matches all-caps string? What's the benefit of converting just the first character to lowercase (as opposed to all characters)?

Comment: A more concise solution that can also handle all these use cases: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35719689/4328383

Answer (score 219):

A shorter solution: Similar to the *editor's* one with a simplified regular expression and fixing the "trailing-underscore" problem:

```
$output = strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $input));
```

[PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/J1eMO) |
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ft57oO/1)

---

Note that cases like `SimpleXML` will be converted to `simple_x_m_l` using the above solution. That can also be considered a wrong usage of camel case notation (correct would be `SimpleXml`) rather than a bug of the algorithm since such cases are always ambiguous - even by grouping uppercase characters to one string (`simple_xml`) such algorithm will always fail in other edge cases like `XMLHTMLConverter` or one-letter words near abbreviations, etc. If you don't mind about the (rather rare) edge cases and want to handle `SimpleXML` correctly, you can use a little more complex solution:

```
$output = ltrim(strtolower(preg_replace('/[A-Z]([A-Z](?![a-z]))*/', '_$0', $input)), '_');
```

[PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/dIo6c) |
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vRuLSr/1)

Comment: Feel free to comment on cletus' answer detailing which test cases you fixed.

Comment: I'm not saying his solution gives wrong results. His solution is just extremely complicated and ineffective.

Comment: Yep, the accept answer is definitely a fail. Jan's solution is awesome!

As a side note, I think this (or a slight variation) is my new, favourite coding test for PHP developers, because the number of answers provided to this question that don't actually work is incredible. It would be a great way to do the initial filtering. :-)

Comment: found the regex used in this solution much more complete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java

Comment: Nice solution for simple use cases and in most usual cases it's enough but the accepted solution can handle more use cases, for example "simpleXML" may be converted to "simple_xml" and not "simple_x_m_l"

Comment: Found this suggestion, liked it and took care of to not convert on start and to keep groups of uppercase letters together. So no worries about SimpleXML -> simple_xml then any longer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's an interesting approach, but it brings new problems. CamelCase notation is used in different ways and some (like `SimpleXML`) are ambiguous and there's nothing to be done about that (except machine learning or other complicated approach). Your method will not handle cases like `ThisIsADonkey` (which will result in `this_is_adonkey`). IMO the `simple_x_m_l` problem is rather a bad usage of CamelCase - `SimpleXml` would be correct. Imagine `SimpleXMLADonkey`... :)

I would prefer to keep my original version and add yours below as an alternative if you agree with that.

Comment: @hakre Since your solution introduced new bugs (see https://regex101.com/r/tIlgOF/1) I've put back my original version (preserving your nice negative-lookbehind trick for the trailing underscore), explained its problems, and added a new solution - based on yours but fixing the problems.

Comment: @JanJakeš: Thanks for the notification, you're right all these pesky bugs. Doing this right is harder than thought.

Answer (score 44):

A concise solution and can handle some tricky use cases:

```
function decamelize($string) {
    return strtolower(preg_replace(['/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/', '/([^_])([A-Z][a-z])/'], '$1_$2', $string));
}
```

Can handle all these cases:

```
simpleTest => simple_test
easy => easy
HTML => html
simpleXML => simple_xml
PDFLoad => pdf_load
startMIDDLELast => start_middle_last
AString => a_string
Some4Numbers234 => some4_numbers234
TEST123String => test123_string
hello_world => hello_world
hello__world => hello__world
_hello_world_ => _hello_world_
hello_World => hello_world
HelloWorld => hello_world
helloWorldFoo => hello_world_foo
hello-world => hello-world
myHTMLFiLe => my_html_fi_le
aBaBaB => a_ba_ba_b
BaBaBa => ba_ba_ba
libC => lib_c
```

You can test this function here: http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/decamelize

Comment: @VivekVardhan which part of this regex you don't understand?

Comment: Uhm, I think that lowercasing non camelcase strings is a side effect, in case the string is not in camel case format the original one should be returned. Infact if you send 'simple_Text' you get Fail: simple_Test => simple_Test [simple_test]. The lowercasing string should be made only and if only the original string is a real camel case string. What do you think about?

Answer (score 36):

The [Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) has a [CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#camelcase-to-snake-case) that has two methods `normalize()` and `denormalize()`. These can be used as follows:

```
$nameConverter = new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter();

echo $nameConverter->normalize('camelCase');
// outputs: camel_case

echo $nameConverter->denormalize('snake_case');
// outputs: snakeCase
```

Comment: Beware!  `$nameConverter->normalize('CamelCase')` outputs `_camel_case` in the current version 3.2 of the Symfony Serializer Component.

Answer (score 25):

Ported from Ruby's `String#camelize` and `String#decamelize`.

```
function decamelize($word) {
  return preg_replace(
    '/(^|[a-z])([A-Z])/e', 
    'strtolower(strlen("\\1") ? "\\1_\\2" : "\\2")',
    $word 
  ); 
}

function camelize($word) { 
  return preg_replace('/(^|_)([a-z])/e', 'strtoupper("\\2")', $word); 
}
```

One trick the above solutions may have missed is the 'e' modifier which causes `preg_replace` to evaluate the replacement string as PHP code.

Comment: The `e` flag for `preg_replace` is being deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: BTW these aren't in Ruby either, but in Rails' inflector library - camelize and underscore. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: This fails for "ThisIsATest". Seems that does not support two consecutive uppercase.

Comment: Just a note: you can use lcfirst to get the first letter to lowercase, then you don't need the `^|` or `strlen`.

Comment: decamelize without deprecation: https://gist.github.com/scones/e09c30e696246fda14578bcf8ab4910a

Answer (score 22):

Most solutions here feel heavy handed. Here's what I use:

```
$underscored = strtolower(
    preg_replace(
        ["/([A-Z]+)/", "/_([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/"], 
        ["_$1", "_$1_$2"], 
        lcfirst($camelCase)
    )
);
```

"CamelCASE" is converted to "camel_case"

- `lcfirst($camelCase)` will lower the first character (avoids 'CamelCASE' converted output to start with an underscore)
- `[A-Z]` finds capital letters
- `+` will treat every consecutive uppercase as a word (avoids 'CamelCASE' to be converted to camel_C_A_S_E)
- Second pattern and replacement are for `ThoseSPECCases` -> `those_spec_cases` instead of `those_speccases`
- `strtolower([…])` turns the output to lowercases

Comment: But it also turns CamelCased to _camel_cased.

Comment: this is great - just add a substr starting at char 1 to get around that issue.

Comment: Excelent! Just need to add `lcfirst` function to $camelCase

Comment: The accepted answer will handle: TestUPSClass into test_ups_class while this will turn it into test_u_p_s_class, something to keep in mind.

Comment: An input string that starts with an allcaps first "word" will be unexpectedly split by this solution because of the `ucfirst()` call.  `USADollarSymbol` becomes `u_sa_dollar_symbol` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/S7HB0) I don't recommend this solution because it has to make two passes through the input string with regex -- a sign of an unrefined pattern.

Answer (score 21):

php does not offer a built in function for this afaik, but here is what I use

```
function uncamelize($camel,$splitter="_") {
    $camel=preg_replace('/(?!^)[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]/', '$0', preg_replace('/(?!^)[[:upper:]]+/', $splitter.'$0', $camel));
    return strtolower($camel);

}
```

the splitter can be specified in the function call, so you can call it like so

```
$camelized="thisStringIsCamelized";
echo uncamelize($camelized,"_");
//echoes "this_string_is_camelized"
echo uncamelize($camelized,"-");
//echoes "this-string-is-camelized"
```

Comment: This fails for "ThisIsATest". Seems that does not support two consecutive uppercase.

Comment: Surely you forgot something as the second replacement does nothing. Apart from this, you can easily make it unicode compatible with `mb_strtolower` and the `/u` option on `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem but couldn't find any answer that satisfies how to convert CamelCase to snake_case, while avoiding duplicate or redundant underscores `_` for names with underscores, or all caps abbreviations.

Th problem is as follows:

```
CamelCaseClass            => camel_case_class
ClassName_WithUnderscores => class_name_with_underscore
FAQ                       => faq
```

The solution I wrote is a simple two functions call, lowercase and search and replace for consecutive lowercase-uppercase letters:

```
strtolower(preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "$1_$2", $name));
```

Comment: By far this is the most concise and useful solution IMO.

Answer (score 8):

"CamelCase" to "camel_case":

```
function camelToSnake($camel)
{
    $snake = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '_$0', $camel);
    $snake = strtolower($snake);
    $snake = ltrim($snake, '_');
    return $snake;
}
```

or:

```
function camelToSnake($camel)
{
    $snake = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', function ($match){
        return '_' . strtolower($match[0]);
    }, $camel);
    return ltrim($snake, '_');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the first approach, but with hyphens to generate `this-kind-of-output`

Answer (score 7):

You need to run a regex through it that matches every uppercase letter except if it is in the beginning and replace it with underscrore plus that letter. An utf-8 solution is this:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$separated = preg_replace('%(?<!^)\p{Lu}%usD', '_$0', 'AaaaBbbbCcccDdddÁáááŐőőő');
$lower = mb_strtolower($separated, 'utf-8');
echo $lower; //aaaa_bbbb_cccc_dddd_áááá_őőőő
```

If you are not sure what case your string is, better to check it first, because this code assumes that the input is `camelCase` instead of `underscore_Case` or `dash-Case`, so if the latters have uppercase letters, it will add underscores to them.

The accepted answer from cletus is way too overcomplicated imho and it works only with latin characters. I find it a really bad solution and wonder why it was accepted at all. Converting `TEST123String` into `test123_string` is not necessarily a valid requirement. I rather kept it simple and separated `ABCccc` into `a_b_cccc` instead of `ab_cccc` because it does not lose information this way and the backward conversion will give the exact same string we started with. Even if you want to do it the other way it is relative easy to write a regex for it with positive lookbehind `(?<!^)\p{Lu}\p{Ll}|(?<=\p{Ll})\p{Lu}` or two regexes without lookbehind if you are not a regex expert. There is no need to split it up into substrings not to mention deciding between `strtolower` and `lcfirst` where using just `strtolower` would be completely fine.

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa If researchers learn how to code from SO, then we have a serious problem...

Comment: Now that you got that personal attack out of your system, please improve your answer.  Assuming that you know how your solution works and why you are using those pattern modifiers, I see no good reason to withhold knowledge from this community.  In case you are considering leaving more snarky responses, I assure you that they don't bother me.  In the time you've taken to comment, you could have completed your answer, we could have deleted our comments, and I could have gone elsewhere to help this site.

Comment: Of course, I have no authority to delete a post with 8 upvotes.  If you would like, you may delete your answer, but it wouldn't be very hard to simply improve it by removing unnecessary pattern modifiers and add an explanation.  The personal attacks have no effect on me.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't think I can delete it either. Feel free to edit it if you want to.

Comment: You have the authority to delete any of your answers that do not wear a green tick, but deleting this answer would be a rash decision.  I think it is rich that you insult me twice then invite me to do your work for you.  The bottomline is that I don't edit code-only answers because: 1. This would reduce the probability of personal growth for the poster.  2. There is no way for me to know _why_ the posted answer was crafted the way it was crafted.  3. I think it is good natured enough to bring awareness of incomplete answers so that volunteers can defend/improve/complete their answers via edit.

Comment: @mickmackusa Well, you want it to be edited, not me. Then probably forget about it, because I no longer maintain my answers here. I kept this account only for upvoting other's answers. I use Quora for Q&A nowadays.

Comment: Just as a note, this fails for already 'snake_case' strings. It will convert to `snake__case' (two underscores).

Comment: Sorry, I meant  'Upper_Snake_Case' strings will be converted to `upper__snake__case' (two underscores).

Comment: @WesleyGonçalves The question was not about how to convert snake case into snake case, you don't need to do anything for that.

Comment: This is the reason why I said "Just as a note" so one that uses it ensures the string is in camel-case.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a PHP 5.4 version and later answer here is the code:

```
function decamelize($word) {
      return $word = preg_replace_callback(
        "/(^|[a-z])([A-Z])/",
        function($m) { return strtolower(strlen($m[1]) ? "$m[1]_$m[2]" : "$m[2]"); },
        $word
    );

}
function camelize($word) {
    return $word = preg_replace_callback(
        "/(^|_)([a-z])/",
        function($m) { return strtoupper("$m[2]"); },
        $word
    );

}
```

Comment: camelize produce "SmsSent" for sms_sent, you need a lcfirst

Answer (score 5):

Short solution:

```
$subject = "PascalCase";
echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\B([A-Z])/', '_$1', $subject));
```

Answer (score 4):

Not fancy at all but simple and speedy as hell:

```
function uncamelize($str) 
{
    $str = lcfirst($str);
    $lc = strtolower($str);
    $result = '';
    $length = strlen($str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= ($str[$i] == $lc[$i] ? '' : '_') . $lc[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}

echo uncamelize('HelloAWorld'); //hello_a_world
```

Comment: `++$i` instead of `$i++` would make it a little bit speedier as well ;)

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Symfony String](https://symfony.com/components/String)

```sh
composer require symfony/string
```

```php
use function Symfony\Component\String\u;

u($string)->snake()->toString()
```

Answer (score 3):

A version that doesn't use regex can be found in the [Alchitect](http://alchitect.com) source:

```
decamelize($str, $glue='_')
{
    $counter  = 0;
    $uc_chars = '';
    $new_str  = array();
    $str_len  = strlen($str);

    for ($x=0; $x<$str_len; ++$x)
    {
        $ascii_val = ord($str[$x]);

        if ($ascii_val >= 65 && $ascii_val <= 90)
        {
            $uc_chars .= $str[$x];
        }
    }

    $tok = strtok($str, $uc_chars);

    while ($tok !== false)
    {
        $new_char  = chr(ord($uc_chars[$counter]) + 32);
        $new_str[] = $new_char . $tok;
        $tok       = strtok($uc_chars);

        ++$counter;
    }

    return implode($new_str, $glue);
}
```

Comment: This is what life would be like without regex :-)

Comment: Heh, yeah. RegEx definitely has its advantages. :)  Raw speed isn't one of them.

Comment: got some funny results with this one for some reason

Comment: Doesn't work for me based on this string : "CamelCaseTestAAATestAA", should have : "camel_case_test_a_a_a_test_a_a", has : ""camel_case_test_aest" ...

Answer (score 3):

So here is a one-liner:

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/(?|([a-z\d])([A-Z])|([^\^])([A-Z][a-z]))/', '$1_$2', $string));
```

Comment: Nice, but it only converts the first appearance, so I'd recommend to add a `g` modifier to this regex.

Comment: @acme, I use it without `g` and it works fine for me.

Comment: For some reason in my case I had to add the `g`. But I can't remember the phrase I tested with.

Answer (score 3):

[danielstjules/Stringy](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy#underscored) provieds a method to convert string from camelcase to snakecase.

```
s('TestUCase')->underscored(); // 'test_u_case'
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.6 provides a very simple way of doing this:

```
 /**
 * Convert a string to snake case.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  string  $delimiter
 * @return string
 */
public static function snake($value, $delimiter = '_'): string
{
    if (!ctype_lower($value)) {
        $value = strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)(?=[A-Z])/u', '$1'.$delimiter, $value));
    }

    return $value;
}
```

What it does: if it sees that there is at least one capital letter in the given string, it uses a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to search for any character (`.`) followed by a capital letter (`(?=[A-Z])`). It then replaces the found character with it's value followed by the separactor `_`.

Comment: This function now seems to be called snake_case() and lives in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The direct port from rails (minus their special handling for :: or acronyms) would be

```
function underscore($word){
    $word = preg_replace('#([A-Z\d]+)([A-Z][a-z])#','\1_\2', $word);
    $word = preg_replace('#([a-z\d])([A-Z])#', '\1_\2', $word);
    return strtolower(strtr($word, '-', '_'));
}
```

Knowing PHP, this will be faster than the manual parsing that's happening in other answers given here. The disadvantage is that you don't get to chose what to use as a separator between words, but that wasn't part of the question.

Also check the [relevant rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L91)

Note that this is intended for use with ASCII identifiers. If you need to do this with characters outside of the ASCII range, use the '/u' modifier for `preg_match`and use `mb_strtolower`.

Comment: You could, if you simply add a parameter that contains the desired character.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my contribution to a six-year-old question with god knows how many answers...

It will convert all words in the provided string that are in camelcase to snakecase. For example "SuperSpecialAwesome and also FizBuzz καιΚάτιΑκόμα" will be converted to "super_special_awesome and also fizz_buzz και_κάτι_ακόμα".

```
mb_strtolower(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?<!\b|_)\p{Lu}/u',
        function ($a) {
            return "_$a[0]";
        },
        'SuperSpecialAwesome'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yii2 have the different function to make the word snake_case from CamelCase.

```
    /**
     * Converts any "CamelCased" into an "underscored_word".
     * @param string $words the word(s) to underscore
     * @return string
     */
    public static function underscore($words)
    {
        return strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=\\w)([A-Z])/', '_\\1', $words));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of shorter ways:

```
function camel_to_snake($input)
{
    return strtolower(ltrim(preg_replace('/([A-Z])/', '_\\1', $input), '_'));
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa - thousands of future researches will be be interested in an elegnant one-liner, and educate themselfs.

Comment: I'm sorry that you have taken that selfish stance.  You certainly could have added an explanation in the time it took you to design and type that snarky reply.  Your answer makes three function calls, but others perform the task in two.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are not using Composer for PHP you are wasting your time.**

```sh
composer require doctrine/inflector
```

```php
use Doctrine\Inflector\InflectorFactory;

// Couple ways to get class name:

// If inside a parent class
$class_name = get_called_class();

// Or just inside the class
$class_name = get_class();

// Or straight get a class name
$class_name = MyCustomClass::class;

// Or, of course, a string
$class_name = 'App\Libs\MyCustomClass';

// Take the name down to the base name:
$class_name = end(explode('\\', $class_name)));

$inflector = InflectorFactory::create()->build();

$inflector->tableize($class_name); // my_custom_class
```

https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/docs/en/index.rst

Answer (score 1):

How to de-camelize without using regex:

```php
function decamelize($str, $glue = '_') {
    $capitals = [];
    $replace  = [];

    foreach(str_split($str) as $index => $char) {
        if(!ctype_upper($char)) {
            continue;
        }

        $capitals[] = $char;
        $replace[]  = ($index > 0 ? $glue : '') . strtolower($char);
    }

    if(count($capitals) > 0) {
        return str_replace($capitals, $replace, $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

**An edit:**

How would I do that in 2019:

PHP 7.3 and before:

```php
function toSnakeCase($str, $glue = '_') {
    return ltrim(
        preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', function ($matches) use ($glue) {
            return $glue . strtolower($matches[0]);
        }, $str),
        $glue
    );

}
```

And with PHP 7.4+:

```php
function toSnakeCase($str, $glue = '_') {
    return ltrim(preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', fn($matches) => $glue . strtolower($matches[0]), $str), $glue);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of empowering/educating future researchers.  Making 1 to 3 function calls on every character in the string then two more function calls after the loop is done is very heavy-handed.  I wouldn't entertain a solution with such poor economy.

Comment: It's an example how it could be done without using regular expressions, not how it should be used in production, so I don't see your point besides that you complain about 5y/o answer that has one upvote and is unlikely to be seen by any researchers.

Comment: I give my attention to all posts, not just highly upvoted ones or recent ones. I am not complaining, I am offering my critique so that researchers with less knowledge can better understand the difference between this answer and other answers. You could have explained in your post that it was merely an academic challenge to avoid regex.  That said, there are ways to make this process more efficient with better coding practices.

Comment: This will always start the snake cased string with the glue: `_pascal_case`

Comment: @AngelinCalu good catch! I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function camel2snake($name) {
    $str_arr = str_split($name);
    foreach ($str_arr as $k => &$v) {
        if (ord($v) >= 64 && ord($v) <= 90) { // A = 64; Z = 90
            $v = strtolower($v);
            $v = ($k != 0) ? '_'.$v : $v;
        }
    }
    return implode('', $str_arr);
}
```

Comment: You can access chars directly using `$name{$k}` (or `$name[$k]`), which would make your code longer, but avoids the large overhead of converting it to and from an array.

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of empowering/educating future researchers.  Your solution, while avoiding the grace of regex, is very heavy-handed and convoluted.  You are splitting on every character and making multiple iterated function calls.  Nominating an empty string as glue is unnecessary.  I would not entertain this solution in one of my projects because there is no elegance, low readability, and _n_ number of unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The worst answer on here was so close to being the best(use a framework). NO DON'T, just take a look at the source code. seeing what a well established framework uses would be a far more reliable approach(tried and tested). The Zend framework has some word filters which fit your needs. [Source](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-filter/tree/master/src/Word).

here is a couple of methods I adapted from the source.

```
function CamelCaseToSeparator($value,$separator = ' ')
{
    if (!is_scalar($value) && !is_array($value)) {
        return $value;
    }
    if (defined('PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR') && preg_match('/\pL/u', 'a') == 1) {
        $pattern     = ['#(?<=(?:\p{Lu}))(\p{Lu}\p{Ll})#', '#(?<=(?:\p{Ll}|\p{Nd}))(\p{Lu})#'];
        $replacement = [$separator . '\1', $separator . '\1'];
    } else {
        $pattern     = ['#(?<=(?:[A-Z]))([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])#', '#(?<=(?:[a-z0-9]))([A-Z])#'];
        $replacement = ['\1' . $separator . '\2', $separator . '\1'];
    }
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value);
}
function CamelCaseToUnderscore($value){
    return CamelCaseToSeparator($value,'_');
}
function CamelCaseToDash($value){
    return CamelCaseToSeparator($value,'-');
}
$string = CamelCaseToUnderscore("CamelCase");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [library](https://github.com/Kolyunya/string-processor) providing this functionality:

```
SnakeCaseFormatter::run('CamelCase'); // Output: "camel_case"
```

Comment: I think you mean "I have created a library providing this functionality". Nothing wrong with self promotion, but don't hide it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Laravel framework, you can use just [snake_case()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-snake-case) method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Laravel framework, a simpler built-in method exists:

```
$converted = Str::snake('fooBar'); // -> foo_bar
```

See documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-snake-case

Answer (score 0):

The open source TurboCommons library contains a general purpose formatCase() method inside the StringUtils class, which lets you convert a string to lots of common case formats, like CamelCase, UpperCamelCase, LowerCamelCase, snake_case, Title Case, and many more.

https://github.com/edertone/TurboCommons

To use it, import the phar file to your project and:

```
use org\turbocommons\src\main\php\utils\StringUtils;

echo StringUtils::formatCase('camelCase', StringUtils::FORMAT_SNAKE_CASE);

// will output 'camel_Case'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'FooBarBaz';

return strtolower(preg_replace('~(?<=\\w)([A-Z])~', '_$1', $str)); // foo_bar_baz
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of empowering/educating future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [the answer posted by syone above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35719689/4710434) as it matched all of my various use cases across all of my projects. However, I also want to use just one regular expression without extra capturing groups.

```
public function decamelize(string $string): string
{
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]|(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z](?=[a-z])/', '_$0', $string));
}
```

[Regex test](https://regex101.com/library/920nJl)

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of [Jan Jakeš](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533226/10022881) answer:

You can replace [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim) with [lcfirst()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) for a bit more of peak-performance. So it will become:

```
$output = strtolower(preg_replace('/[A-Z]([A-Z](?![a-z]))*/', '_$0', lcfirst($text)));
```

Here is simple [performance test](https://onlinephp.io/c/df2fe)

Answer (score -1):

It's easy using the Filter classes of the Zend [Word Filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.filter.word.html):

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\Utility;

use Zend\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToUnderscore;
use Zend\Filter\Word\UnderscoreToCamelCase;

class String
{
    public function test()
    {
        $underscoredStrings = array(
            'simple_test',
            'easy',
            'html',
            'simple_xml',
            'pdf_load',
            'start_middle_last',
            'a_string',
            'some4_numbers234',
            'test123_string',
        );
        $camelCasedStrings = array(
            'simpleTest',
            'easy',
            'HTML',
            'simpleXML',
            'PDFLoad',
            'startMIDDLELast',
            'AString',
            'Some4Numbers234',
            'TEST123String',
        );
        echo PHP_EOL . '-----' . 'underscoreToCamelCase' . '-----' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($underscoredStrings as $rawString) {
            $filteredString = $this->underscoreToCamelCase($rawString);
            echo PHP_EOL . $rawString . ' >>> ' . $filteredString . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL . '-----' . 'camelCaseToUnderscore' . '-----' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($camelCasedStrings as $rawString) {
            $filteredString = $this->camelCaseToUnderscore($rawString);
            echo PHP_EOL . $rawString . ' >>> ' . $filteredString . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    public function camelCaseToUnderscore($input)
    {
        $camelCaseToSeparatorFilter = new CamelCaseToUnderscore();
        $result = $camelCaseToSeparatorFilter->filter($input);
        $result = strtolower($result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function underscoreToCamelCase($input)
    {
        $underscoreToCamelCaseFilter = new UnderscoreToCamelCase();
        $result = $underscoreToCamelCaseFilter->filter($input);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> -----underscoreToCamelCase-----
>
> simple_test >>> SimpleTest
>
> easy >>> Easy
>
> html >>> Html
>
> simple_xml >>> SimpleXml
>
> pdf_load >>> PdfLoad
>
> start_middle_last >>> StartMiddleLast
>
> a_string >>> AString
>
> some4_numbers234 >>> Some4Numbers234
>
> test123_string >>> Test123String
>
> -----camelCaseToUnderscore-----
>
> simpleTest >>> simple_test
>
> easy >>> easy
>
> HTML >>> html
>
> simpleXML >>> simple_xml
>
> PDFLoad >>> pdf_load
>
> startMIDDLELast >>> start_middle_last
>
> AString >>> a_string
>
> Some4Numbers234 >>> some4_numbers234
>
> TEST123String >>> test123_string

Answer (score -1):

IF you could start with:

```
$string = 'Camel_Case'; // underscore or any other separator...
```

Then you could convert to either case just with:

```
$pascal = str_replace("_", "", $string);
$snake = strtolower($string);
```

Or any other cases:

```
$capitalized = str_replace("_", " ", $string); // Camel Case
$constant = strtoupper($string);               // CAMEL_CASE
$train = str_replace("_", "-", $snake);        // camel-case
```