# How do I convert underscore into human-readable names in Java?

Tags: java, string

I'd like to write a method that converts CamelCase into a human-readable name.
This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java) but now with underscore.

Here's the test case:

```
public void testSplitUnderscore() {
    assertEquals("lowercase", splitUnderscore("lowercase"));
    assertEquals("Class", splitUnderscore("Class"));
    assertEquals("My Class", splitUnderscore("My_Class"));
    assertEquals("HTML", splitUnderscore("HTML"));
    assertEquals("PDF Loader", splitUnderscore("PDF_Loader"));
    assertEquals("A String", splitUnderscore("A_String"));
    assertEquals("Simple XML Parser", splitUnderscore("Simple_XML_Parser"));
    assertEquals("GL 11 Version", splitUnderscore("GL_11_Version"));
    assertEquals("99 Bottles", splitUnderscore("99_Bottle"));
    assertEquals("May 5", splitUnderscore("May_5"));
    assertEquals("BFG 9000", splitUnderscore("BFG_9000"));
    assertEquals("beginning", splitUnderscore("_beginning"));
    assertEquals("end", splitUnderscore("end_"));
    assertEquals("double middle", splitUnderscore("double__middle"));
    assertEquals("double end", splitUnderscore("double_end__"));
    assertEquals("double start", splitUnderscore("__double_start"));
    assertEquals("double start middle end", splitUnderscore("__double_start__middle_end__"));
}
```

Comment: Check out [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) ... DRY.

Comment: Why all the down votes? How can I improve the question?

Comment: @EddieB What is DRY? I didn't find any projects named DRY.

Comment: DRY ~ Dont Repeat Yourself :) ~ Apache commons already has those utilities.

Comment: Ah yes DRY. What project has that functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A naive way of accomplishing this would be to replace every `'_'` with a `' '`, and then trim the whitespaces off the final string:

```
public static String splitUnderscore(String s) {
    return s.replace("_", " ").trim();
}
```

While the above works for most cases, to handle multiple adjacent underscores we could use a regular expression to replace any number of consecutive underscores with a single `' '`:

```
public static String splitUnderscore(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("_{1,}", " ").trim();
}
```

Comment: This will pass your test cases.

Comment: How can this work with the extra double underscores?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
String.replace('_', " ").trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a couple more test cases:

```
assertEquals("A String", splitUnderscore("double__middle"));
assertEquals("A String", splitUnderscore("double_end__"));
assertEquals("A String", splitUnderscore("__double_start"));
assertEquals("A String", splitUnderscore("__double_start__middle_end__"));
```

Comment: Added the extra tests to the question.