# Leaving a space where necessary when invoking getClass().getSimpleName()

Tags: java, inheritance

Is there a way of leaving a space where it is necessary when invoking `getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase()` method?

For instance, I have several different classes whose names are `PublicTransportation`, `CityBus`, `Metro`, `Tram`, `Ferry`, `Aircraft`.

I have defined my `toString()` methods but would like to leave a space between `Public` and `Transportation`. Same thing for the `CityBus` class. Here are my `toString()` methods:

```
//PublicTransportation class
public String toString()
{
    return "This " + getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + " costs " + getTicketPrice() + ". It has " + getNumOfStops() + " number of stops.";
}

//CityBus class
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " It's route number is " + getRouteNum()
            + ".\nIt's operation start year is " + getBeginOpYear() + ". The line name is " + getLineName() + ". The driver is " 
            + getDriverName() + ".";
}
```

Comment: i think your question is not clear can you explain more with some examples?

Comment: `getSimpleName` is not related to `toString` in any way: `toString` is a method that might return different results for different instances while `getSimpleName` is a class method!

Comment: You could save the `getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase()` result in a variable and then add the space as wanted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be a regex. For instance, `System.out.println("CityBus".replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2"))`   will print out `City Bus` (with a space). So in your case, `toString()` would be something like this:

```
public String toString()
{
    String expandedName = getClass().getSimpleName().replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
    return "This " + expandedName + " costs " + getTicketPrice() + ". It has " + getNumOfStops() + " number of stops.";
}
```

It can be made a little better by making the `expandedName` string `static` so we don't do the regex replacement on each call to `toString()`, but just once per class.

**Edit:**

`replaceAll()` takes two [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html), and replaces one with the other. The regex being replaced is `([a-z])([A-Z])`, which translates to "a lower case letter, followed by an upper case letter" both letters are in parenthesis, which makes them [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). I then replace it with `$1 $2` which means "capture group 1, space, capture group 2".

Comment: This works best! Would you mind explaining what are the parameters passed in the replaceAll() method?

Comment: @JKawa I've added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do it in this way, because you get only class name and make it to lower case.

If possible, you can try to define you own `getSimpleName` method (or methods) returns class name in your wished format.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the class name by camel case using regex with:

`getClass().getSimpleName().split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")`

Then use a StringBuffer to construct the final string from the resulting array.