# Return different field names Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, naming

I am using the full calendar open source library in an application. I am using Laravel at the back end. Now most JavaScript libraries use cameCase in their variable names. The thing is that on the back end Laravel has a naming convention in tables I guess which uses underscored_in_the_column_name.

Now the create() method comes very handy and creates a new resource with the input data coming and I don't have to assign multiple fields manually. But now since I am working with the library, it is sending the data as camelCase which is an issue both ways because when I return data from the server to the calendar I again have to make sure that the fields are in camelCase instead of underscores_between_them.

How do I do this? Is there a way to accomplish this in Laravel or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Try the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993721/how-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case)

Comment: @MattBurrow You can do the same with Laravel's [helper functions for strings](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#strings). e.g. `snake_case()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it you basically have two options here:

### 1. Change the database to camelCase

snake_case is just Laravel's *convention* it not required to have your column names like that. So you could simply change the names to camelCase and set the `$snakeAttributes` option in your model(s) to false:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
}
```

Then you should be able to `create()` and `get()` your model with camelCase attribute names.

---

### 2. Override some methods

If you want to keep your db tables like they are you will have to override some methods in your model:

First, for array/JSON conversion:

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $renamed = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $renamed[camel_case($key)] = $value;
    }
    return $renamed;
}
```

Then for setting and getting single attributes:

```
public function getAttribute($key){
    $key = snake_case($key);
    return parent::getAttribute($key);
}

public function setAttribute($key, $value){
    $key = snake_case($key);
    parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```