# Separate string in php by upper case letters

Tags: php, regex, html

I'm developing an application that takes a full name of a person and then processes it. For example, if the user enters the name like this:

```
"AlanMichel"
```

Then the result must be:

```
"Alan Michel"
```

I didn't know how I can do that in the php. Anyone can help please?

Comment: With minimal modification, you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533226/1207049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$str = "AlanMichel";
$name = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$str);

echo implode( " ", $name );
```

This will result to:

```
Alan Michel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function splitAtUpperCase($s) {
        return preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

$str = "AlanMichel";
$strArray = splitAtUpperCase($str));
echo $strArray[0]; //first name
echo $strArray[1]; //second name
```

**Output**

```
Alan
Michel
```

If you don't need the array itself, you can just preprend uppercase characters (except the first) with a space

```
echo  preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z])/', ' \\1', $str);
```